# Regex, how to ignore numbers' period?

Tags: regex

I want to split by period as an end of a sentence, but it split numbers as well ex: 3.25.
I have this regex `(?![0-9])\.(?![0-9])` but it ignores sentences that start or end by numbers.

Edit:
and if possible abbreviations like U.S.A, like @Bamar mentioned.

thank you,

Comment: The one on the left needs to be a lookbehind, not a lookahead.

Comment: This will also split when the period is part of an abbreviation like `U.S.A.`

Comment: @Barmar You saved me in the future.

Comment: If the sentences are well formatted, you can split on a period followed by a space. It depends on the quality of your inputs.

Comment: @Kit Unless the period is at the end of the input, or it's quoted, like `He said, "It doesn't work."`

Comment: @Kit, the period at the end of a sentence may be at the end of the string, so better to split on a period not followed by anything other than a space (`\.(?!\S)`).

Comment: Identifying periods that terminate sentences is effectively not possible. Two sentences or one: "He knew John P. Jones was the killer."? (Perhaps that's why wordsmiths of yore put two spaces after sentences that did not end a paragraph.)